# Can't register an windows phone developers account - "Something happened while saving your changes. Try again"

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create an Windows Phone developers account, but it's says "Something happened while saving your changes. Try again" during the registration. 
I have tryed doing the recommended workaround
 ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpregister/thread/044dfcb3-70f8-46fc-b79f-f654dca66122)  but i doesn't work, so no developers account for me. This is very frustration, sincs there is no logical error, just a useless message.

Does anyone have any thoughts on or other workarounds?

Thanks

Bjørn

Comment: Did you try with Internet Explorer?

Comment: yes, I have tryed to use IE and Chrome. Have also tryed home and work computer. Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'll found a new workaround, logged in to my MSDN account. After logging in to the MSDN account   I kept the MSDN-tab (more exact, the "my account"- tab) open and then tried to register at the windows phone developers page - Success!

See this link for another workaround (Almost at the bottom) : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpregister/thread/044dfcb3-70f8-46fc-b79f-f654dca66122

Finally I have a Windows Phone developers account.

Answer (score 0):

Work Around is simple! It worked for me.

The problem is with the Phone entry.

If you are from US, +1 for the first text box and xxx for the area code in the second text box and the remaining phone number in the third text box.

I wish, microsoft should have captured this in the client side validation and wondering the issue persists even now, without permanent fix or error handling.